# My if bash script always execute the break

Tags: bash, scripting, exit

I`m making a script to rename files in a folder. The new name for the files is in a config file. I have to be sure that the file I want to rename corresponds to the current one in the config file. My code is that:

```
#!/bin/bash

. conf.cfg

number_of_files=`echo "$filename"|wc -l`

#echo "$number_of_files"
existing_files=`find iputemp/ `
echo "$existing_files"

iterations=`echo "$existing_files"|wc -l`

#echo "$filename"

for x in `seq 1 $iterations`; do
        current_file_name=`echo "$filename"|sed -n "$x"p`
        echo "$current_file_name"
        echo "$x"
        for z in `seq 1 $number_of_files`; do
                this_file=$(echo "$existing_files"|sed -n ${z}p|cut -d '/' -f2)
                echo "$z"
                if [[ ${current_file_name} == *${this_file}* ]]; then
                        echo "EXIST"
                        mv iputemp/${tile} ${current_file_name}
                        sleep 0.5
                        break
                fi
        done
done
```

My problem is that the second loop always execute the break and I don`t know why, can someone help me please?

Comment: I thought in bash the _is equal to_ operator was a single `=` and not double.

Comment: Try to run the script on terminal as follow: `bash -x ./my-script.sh`. It'll give you debug info, could be helpful. However, when you're doing this I would comment out the `mv` command since the script is not working as expected. Possibly just print ht e file name with the echo as well, so you'll know which ones will be moved.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your test statement into quotes:

```
if [[ "${current_file_name}" == "*${this_file}*" ]];
```

Comment: I don't think there is a need for that. The regex might not work with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can drop the parantheses:

```
if [[ "$current_file_name" = "$this_file" ]]; then
```

also, I'd recommend using only one equal sign, it works more reliable in my experience.

Comment: par***e***ntheses not parantheses... with an "e"

Comment: Actually, {  } are not parentheses - the phrase "curly brackets" seems more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, english is my second language.